# How to alert checkbox dynamically from a php while loop to jquery function

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

In my page i am iterating values based on the database table. I have to give a alert message when i check my radio button residing in the php while loop, when users click on it.

I tried the below code, but its not working. When i am clicking on any of  the radio button from my page then , i am not getting alert message . Please help me to solve my  problem.

my php code:

```
      <?php  $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM group_expenditure_details where creater_id =   
       '$uid'");
           $a=0; 
           while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
               {

                       echo "<tr>";
                           echo "<td width='20%' align='center'><input type='checkbox'  
       name='test".$a++."'  id='test".$a++."' value='1'  /></td>";
                               echo "</tr>";
                }
              echo "</table>";
              echo "</div>";
              mysql_close($con);
           ?>
```

My Jquery code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function(){
             <?php  $od=$_SESSION['id']; $result1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM            
                   group_expenditure_details where creater_id = '$od'");  $a=0;
             while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result1))  {  ?>
                $('<?php  '#test'.$a++?>').click(function(){
            <?php } ?>
                    alert('clicked');
                });
            }); 
    </script>
```

Comment: you don't generate click handlers from loop. That's very bad.Follow Dipesh Parmarrs solution and replace your js entirely.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$(function()
{
    $('input[id^="test"]').on('click',function()
    {
        alert('Clicked');
    });
});
```

what `$('input[id^="test"]')` this will do is select all the `input` which `id` is starts with `test`.

`.on` is replacement of `.live()` and `.delegate()` in new version of jQuery.

`.on()` works on dyanmically loaded content so if `checkbox` added later then `click` event will also work on newly added `DOM`.

Comment: but i said already, i have a single checkbox in a loop, which creates multiple id. when click on any specific checkbox then alert message should be poppup

Comment: And what things i have to change in my php script i have shown above my php scripts?

Comment: @BurlsWillis no need to change php code just use above answered jQuery `code`

Comment: well its working fine with your above j query function. i kept `<input type='checkbox' id='test' value='12'/>`  . Now instead of alert message ,i want this checkbox value to be shown in alert box. How to  do this?

Comment: @BurlsWillis just replace `alert()` code with `alert($(this).val());`

Comment: Well its working fine. I have a question. I am from Bangalore, I want to learn jquery nicely as you know. Can you give me suggestions to achieve this goal?  Or how you learn jquery !  - I am java developer, i know jquery litle bit , but i want to learn very perfectly like you

Comment: @BurlsWillis just spend time and go through example given in jquery.com and try it on your own...also learn about DOM and selectors thats it.

Comment: thank you very much. Can you give me your phone#, so that if i am struct with   any doubt in jquery,then i can call you and ask!

Comment: @BurlsWillis its not safe place to share personal info but you can mail me on my mail id dipeshbeckham@gmail.com

Comment: this is my email ashutosh13g@gmail.com , it will be safe to send your phone# . Please send it

Answer (score 0):

I'll add a class attribute to the radio buttons

```
<input type='checkbox' class="my-radio" name='test".$a."'  id='test".$a."' value='1'  />
```

Then

```
$(function(){
    $('.my-radio').click(function(){
        alert('Clicked');
    });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$(function(){  //ensure dom is ready
    $('input[id^=test]').click(function(){ //id starts with test
        alert('Clicked');
    });
});
```

Don't use any PHP in your javascript for this. The way you construct your `id='test'.$a` will ensure that the id `always starts with test. So within that click function above, we have handled the pattern.

Comment: but i said already, i have a single checkbox in a loop, which creates multiple id. when click on any specific checkbox then alert message should be poppup